# Reduce memory usage of Python processes

Tags: python, memory, process

I was working on a code needing processes and I was surprised by the memory used by each process. I do not have an extensive knowledge about processes and threads, and maybe it's really logical, but I couldn't find out the reason for that memory consumption, and how to reduce it.

The following code creates a big 'info' variable, and create 5 processes with almost no information:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import time

def proc(speific_list, some_info):
    time.sleep(10)

def jobs():
    manager = Manager()
    specific_list = manager.list()
    jobs = []
    info = "Hello"
    for i in xrange(0,25):
        info += info
    for job_id in xrange(0,5):
        d = Process(name='proc', target=proc, args=(specific_list, 35))
        d.daemon = True            
        d.start()
        jobs.append(d)

    for job in jobs:
        job.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs()
```

The problem is that the main process will have the 'info' variable, around 170MB, and do not send it to the other processes. But each process will take 170MB, even if I never sent this variable. For now I use a very ugly solution to avoid that problem - using a file, destroying the 'info' before creating the process, reading only what needed from the file - but that's just a patch and there is surely another solution.

1. Why is each process getting a copy of the variable used by the main process?
2. How to avoid that?

Edit:

For my particular case, 'info' is a 600MB list and each process receives a part of the 'info', a working solution seems to copy the list to a manager.list() and destroy the initial 'info'. That way I can reduce the memory usage. But I would like a solution working for more general projects. It's not convenient - nor always possible - to delete the biggest variables before creating processes.

Comment: I'm not a Python expert, but I imagine `Process` just forks the process.  So every process is identical to the original, including its memory usage.  But it's only virtual memory usage you're seeing, copy-on-write (assuming you're using *nix here) means that there's only one copy of the physical memory that backs this.

Comment: Yes. Each python process maps to a system process, which therefore gets a copy of the dataspace. So yes, it'd be more efficient to load/create the big `info` variable after the processes have been created. You can go for threads, which share the dataspace, but then there would be other cons. It's a big topic, it really depends on what you need to do, if the app is I/O bound, etc.

Comment: I saw threads mentioned...probably you've already heard about Python's GIL: threads in python only give the multi threading feeling, but actually, there's only one python thread running at a certain time; even if there are multiple units (cores/logical processors) able to run threads in parallel.

Comment: For my project, I create a 600MB list ('info'), but I send part of this list to each process, that way each process analyze a part of it. So I cannot create the 'info' after. I would prefer to avoid Threads if possible (there are not particularly efficient for the computation involved on each part of the list).@CristiFati indeed, that's why I would prefer to avoid them